# SPTrack states it's loaded, but metadata isn't

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

At one point, I'm loading a number of `SPTrack`s in an `NSArray`. When on a sketchy internet connection (i.e. connecting/disconnecting during load), I'm experiencing some unexpected (?) loading results: tracks are included in the `loadedItems` array, but their metadata isn't loaded.

According to `SPTrack.h`, all data should be loaded when `loaded` is `YES`:

```
/** Returns `YES` if the track has finished loading and all data is available. */ 
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=isLoaded) BOOL loaded;
```

**Am I doing something wrong, or could this be an issue with CocoaLibSpotify?**

---

***My code:***

```
[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:tracks timeout:kTrackLoadingTimeout then:^(NSArray *loadedItems, NSArray *notLoadedItems) {
    for (SPTrack *track in loadedItems) {
            NSLog(@"%@ loaded %i", track, track.loaded);
    }

    // ... then do stuff with the loaded tracks

}];
```

***Console output:***

```
<SPTrack: 0xc65c180>: Teardrop loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3d86f0>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3b5730>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3ca660>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3c9c50>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3c9cf0>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3c96c0>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3c9820>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3ca1a0>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3c9020>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc36fcf0>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3c8e60>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3c8c00>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3c8920>: 5 O'Clock Featuring Lily Allen & Wiz Khalifa loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3c8660>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc394850>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3ec040>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3896a0>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3c83e0>: (null) loaded 1
<SPTrack: 0xc3be530>: (null) loaded 1
```

Comment: Older versions of CocoaLibSpotify had a bug where the `loaded` flag would get set before metadata was applied. Otherwise, make a unit test!